# MS Access string manipulation in a query

Tags: string, ms-access

In Access I have an ID in a field that follows the convention of `xx=Daniel Lane/Other info`

In an Access query how would I go about extracting the name from between the `=` and `/`

Comment: Have *you* tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MS Access` you can use the `trim()` function in your query.

I would advise looking at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286238) article at Microsoft.

the significant part to your query in particular would be the following example there:

**Middle Initial:**
Original Entry in [Names]: "John P. Doe"
Returned by Expression: **P.**
Expression: Expr: `Trim(Mid([Names],InStr(1,[Names]," ")+1,InStr(InStr _ (1, [Names], " ")+1,[Names]," ")-InStr(1,[Names]," ")))`

Of course, you need to modify it to find your `=` and `/` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a custom VBA function that the query can then call:

```
Function ExtractName(Value)
  If IsNull(Value) Then GoTo Invalid
  Dim EqualsPos As Long, StrokePos As Long
  EqualsPos = InStr(Value, "=")
  If EqualsPos = 0 Then GoTo Invalid
  StrokePos = InStr(EqualsPos + 1, Value, "/")
  If StrokePos = 0 Then GoTo Invalid
  ExtractName = Mid(Value, EqualsPos + 1, StrokePos - EqualsPos - 1)
  Exit Function
Invalid:
  ExtractName = Null
End Function
```